# Miscalculation of worked days in payroll

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created a working schedule like below.

[image]

And assigned to a contract.
When i create a payroll for an employee, odoo miscalculate worked days.

The issue is, whenever i define working time between `midnight to morning`  like `22:00 - 06:00`, `21:00 - 05:00` etc.

If i define like '00:00 - 08:00`, it working fine.

Here is the screenshot for payroll.

[image]

How can i resolve this?
Is it bug or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign from (22-6), then use two working time for a single day. (0-6) and (22-24). if you give (22-6) in a day, it will not be included in calculation.

If it is necessary for you to give in the format you have specified, then you should change working day calculation. Have a look at the onchange of employee in hr.payroll.

*@api.onchange('employee_id', 'date_from', 'date_to')
def onchange_employee(self):*

Its better to use in the correct format than changing code.